# Aspx page respose very slow before restart application pool

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I got website that running  on IIS7 that response very slow during weekend night time, after restarting the application pool the website would response fast for certain of time. As time goes (maybe few hours) the website response become slow again.

I open the resource monitor at task manager, and look for the process for the website, the Average CPU is like 6-8, what makes me curious is the Receive B/s go up to 0.8-1MB while the Sent B/s only have 200B, I don't know if that is relevant.

So I was hoping to get an insight of what is the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague. For starters, are we talking a web app, connected to a database? If so, what type of database? There could be any number of causes for this.

But from the sounds of it, I would first start with any database queries you have running. I had a similar issue to yours with a web app, which turned out to be the result of an inefficient SQL Stored Procedure. The site would slow down and grind almost to a halt, but would spring back to life after the app pool was restarted. Rewriting the main Sproc solved the problem.

Comment: i see, never thought of sql stored procedure could cause all this problem, btw it did connect to a database and i am using mssql 2008. anyway i go dig into it, thanks